# How does python print or save big data without ellipsis?

Tags: python, printing

I need to print or save a list with big data completely while I only can print partial data. The specific condition is like the picture.

[the situation of python print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y67FI.jpg)

### When I try to save this data, I can only save partial data too.But now I need to save or print all the data. I could save the data as .mat, But I cannot read it in java.Please help me.

Sorry, I didn't post my code fragment.
[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml6A8.jpg)

Comment: You should post a fragment of the code you're using

Comment: To get the most friendly response and best advice here of SO, it helps to post [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For future reference, [please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text?cb=1).

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.savetxt`:

```
b = np.zeros((10000, 10000))
np.savetxt('output.txt', b)
```

So that you can get the exact format that you want, `savetxt` has many options.  You can read about them [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html).  One particularly useful option is to set a format string to control how the numbers are written.  For example:

```
np.savetxt('output2.txt', b, fmt='%5.2f')
```